# Can I have a two line caption in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can I have a two line caption in pandas dataframe?

Create dataframe with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['John','Harry','Gary','Richard','Anna','Richard','Gary','Richard'], 'Age' : [25,32,37,43,44,56,37,22],  'Zone' : ['East','West','North','South','East','West','North', 'South']})
df=df.drop_duplicates('Name',keep='first')
df.style.set_caption("Team Members Per Zone")
```

which outputs:

```
Team Members Per Zone
Name    Age Zone
0   John    25  East
1   Harry   32  West
4   Anna    44  East
6   Gary    37  North
7   Richard 22  South
```

However I'd like it to look like:

```
   Team Members 
     Per Zone
Name    Age Zone
0   John    25  East
1   Harry   32  West
4   Anna    44  East
6   Gary    37  North
7   Richard 22  South
```

Comment: Have you tried with \n ?

Comment: Hi yes. Has no impact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a break works for me in JupyterLab:

```
df.style.set_caption('This is line one <br> This is line two')
```

Comment: Works in Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with \n ? (Sorry too low reputation to just comment.

Comment: I did. Has no impact.